# deploying to ubuntu instance on aws from windows

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-ec2, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I want to deploy a python project to ubuntu instance on aws from a windows operating system, but all tutorials I have encountered either use ubuntu or mac as their development/local machine.

Is the deployment from windows the same i.e. after createing the instance all I would then be doing from the local windows system would be running inside the ubuntu instance?

is there any tutorial which can help me achieve my objective?

Note i am deploying directly without git.
ANy help would be appreciated

Answer (score 1):

To transfer files to an ubuntu instance you could use SSH, from windows you could download an SSH client such as Mobaxterm   (https://mobaxterm.mobatek.net/)! or download Windows Subsystem for Linux (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)! then use SCP to copy files (https://www.computerhope.com/unix/scp.htm)!. Both options require that you have the .pem security file for your instance

Comment: Thanks I would try that out and let you know

Comment: Also Powershell is able to run the same linux commands

Answer (score 1):

Your best bet is going to be installing WSL(Windows Subsystem for Linux) and using that to run bash commands. This will make your life a whole lot easier as you won't have to look for Windows specific tutorials and you can now follow Ubuntu/Linux tutorials.

What is WSL? It is essentially a Linux VM built into Windows. It will provide you with a terminal running Ubuntu or pretty much any other Linux distro you could want.

[How to install WSL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10)